# Dynamically change sheet name inside formula without changing row and column

Tags: google-sheets

I have this formula for my payroll sheet. It is a formula to determined how many cut the employee have to pay everytime they late in clocking in :

```
=(75000*Januari!AI4)+(150000*Januari!AI3)
```

I want to make Januari! change automatically based on cell with dropdown. So when i choose the dropdown to Februari, i expect a formula to change like this :

```
=(75000*Februari!AI4)+(150000*Februari!AI3)
```

But how could i accomplish this ?

I try concat and concatenate but it returned to string or error

Comment: You need `INDIRECT()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have dropdown in `A1` cell. Then use-

```
=(75000*INDIRECT(A1 & "!AI4"))+(150000*INDIRECT(A1 & "!AI3"))
```